# Is the word 'virtu' widely understood?

Tags: meaning

I'm going to use this word as a synonym of *artwork*, but some dictionaries seem to not contain its definition. So I'd like to know if that word is understood by the wide audience in the way I described, or they may confuse it with, for example, *virtue*?

Comment: My dictionary says it means "knowledge or expertise of the fine arts".

Comment: @GEdgar And then it says "curios or objets d'art collectively". And it says, that the phrase "articles (or object) of virtu" means "an article that is interesting because of its antiquity, beauty, quality of workmanship, etc." Actually I didn't mean, that it is a synonym, rather it can add the idea of "artwork" when used in combination with some other word.

Answer (score 4):

No, the word "virtu" as a synonym for "artwork" is not at all in common usage and would be unintelligible for 99 percent of your audience...unless your audience is art conservators and art historians.